# Find pure strategy Nash equilibrium in 3-player game

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

[image]

The answer of this question says that The pure strategy Nash equilibria of this game are: (U ; L; A), (D; R; A) and
(D; R; B).

But this answer does not make sense for me. I found that (U,L,A), (U,R,A), (D,R,B).

please explain the reason for the original answer thank you.

Note that I have calculated best responses like that

[image]

Comment: DRA cannot be a nash equilibrium because it is profitable for player 3 to deviate and play B. I've solved the game and arrive at the same conclusion as you. So either it is a typo or the order of the payoffs inside each matrix is other than player 1, player 2, player 3

Comment: Okay thank you for your feedback @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera